# OutOfMemoryException when uploading file to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, out-of-memory, entity-framework-6

I have an `MVC` application that requires me to upload a data file to it. The need for the data file is to update records in our database.

The issue is that when I try to read the file to save to the database, I get an `OutOfMemoryException`. The size of the file I am uploading is `186MB`. I am successful on a smaller file, roughly `120MB`.

It throws the exception on the `CopyTo` line of code. However, I have tried using a `BinaryReader` and even saving the file to the sever and reading it back and neither way made a difference. Same `exception` gets thrown.
My controller action is:

```
public ActionResult UpdateAddresses(HttpPostedFileBase addressFile)
{
    using (var addressStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        addressFile.InputStream.CopyTo(addressStream);
        var addressFileName = addressFile.FileName;
        addressFile = null;

        documentService.AddDocument(DateTime.Now, addressFile.FileName, FileTypes.ProducerAddressUpdate, addressStream.ToArray(), this.CurrentUser.AccountName);
    }

    return Index();
}
```

I have also tried reading in the `strea`m. The problem with that approach is that I get an `out of memory exception` as soon as I declare the `byte[]`. Its as if the `byte array` is too large for `.NET` to handle. This would surprise me as a file of this size is not that large. At least not compared to gigabytes of data.

Comment: Your question led me to some interesting google results that may help you.  [This](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/443262-outofmemoryexception-when-loading-huge-file-into-memorystream#post1688576) Q&A about a outofmemory exception leads to an answer by Jon Skeet.  He links to [this](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/readbinary.html) site, which details a method of using an array of smaller byte streams to buffer the data.  Some of these methods may be of use here.

Comment: Entity Framework is not well suited to storing large binary blobs into a SQL database. This is because it does not support `Stream`s. 186MB is much bigger than 85kB, which means you'll be using the Large Object Heap, and thrashing it at that (most likely creating about 500MB worth of continuous objects). I would suggest you directly stream the file into the database using ADO.Net rather than use EF. The OOME is most likely due to memory fragmentation.

Comment: @Tommy - I tried two different approaches from the site you mentioned. Both still generate the OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @Aron - I agree completely and I might end up having to use ADO.NET. However, I cannot even read the file in which is going to be a bigger issue later on. Eventually, my nightly process has to read this file out of the database and make changes to the database accordingly.

Comment: @Guthwulf You could Stream the file out into a temp FileStream, then parse it there.

Comment: @Guthwulf - good deal, sorry I couldn't be more helpful!